# How to host agnostic-from-project authentication frontend

Tags: authentication, next.js, frontend, vercel

I need the authentication frontend (login/signup) to be an independent project to which different web applications can access in order to authenticate the user.

**Example**

Similar to OpenAI with ChatGPT. The user can log in from both the openai landing site or from the chatGPT site. However, both options redirect the user to the same authentication independent site.

**Question**

If I host this authentication frontend on vercel with a 'static' DNS, e.g. "my-auth.com" every user would have access without needing to go through the landing or the product site. How could I make it to only redirect users that clicked the Log in button on whichever of my expected sites (landing, product...)?